# How to enable doclint in Bazel

Tags: bazel, bazel-java

It seems to me that doclint is not enabled by default.

For instance, this code should fail.

```
/**
  * List of errors:
  * <ul><li>Unclosed list
  */
static final class FooBar{}
```

How to turn on doclint in Bazel?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if declint is part of the toolchain but https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_go/blob/master/go/nogo.rst might be useful here.